# Gift Aid Payments - Integrating a payments system API into a charity site

Tags: php, paypal, payment-processing

Ambiguous question, I know. But anyway, I'm developing a client's site that will enable users to donate to people doing charity work abroad. I need the users of the site who create their profiles to be able to input their PayPal email address (for example) and as such any users who click the big 'Donate' button on their profile can donate directly to them.

I'm sure this is possible, at least using the PayPal API. However since this is all for charity work, I'd like to implement '[Gift Aid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_Aid)' - read about it at the link.

My problem is finding a payment system that we can use that has Gift Aid either 'built in' or that can make a clear definition between which payments are gift-aided and which are not - sorry if this isn't making any sense!

So ideally I'm looking for a payments processor that can integrate as seamlessly as possible into the client's site which I'm developing in PHP, can support Gift Aid automatically - or if not, clearly specify which payments ticked the 'Gift Aid' option - and supports payments from credit and debit card sources, etc. I hope this is understandable now!

I know there's obviously the PayPal API but I'm sure there are others, I'm just not too sure where to start looking or if the whole Gift-Aid thingy is even possible with transactions like this. Would it be more convienient just to code our own system?

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use PayPal, definately. Making the effort to learn their API is not hard. Coding your own solution would be a nightmare. Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Thanks Magnus. In the end we did go with PayPal and the site works great, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at what CTT have to offer:  http://www.ctt.org/products__services/cp_terminal/default.asp they have their own payment Gateway called CPterminal/CPWeb which is designed for charities.